# JBoss Fuse Server not releasing port even after stopping bundle

Tags: linux, apache-camel, apache-karaf, jbossfuse, hotdeploy

I have deployed 2 bundle. Both are exposing Rest Webservice on port 9001 and 9002. Now when i go to JBoss Fuse installed directly, run karaf.sh which will opne karaf console. I tried to list all bundle and , stop bundle with their bundle id's. However the bundle which is exposing a service on 9001 doesn't close. After stopping both bundle when i run *netstat -anp | grep 9001 i "tcp  0  0 ::ffff:172.16.50.31:9001    :::*    LISTEN      2511/java" but when i run same command for 9002 it doesnt show any process which means port 9002 was released when i stopped bundle corresponding to it but same didnt happen for 9001. I am doing hot deployment of jar's i.e placing jar into deploy folder of JBoss Fuse.

Comment: Is your bundle actually stopped? What does `osgi:list` say about it? You may need to increase logging levels, to trace what is going on in your bundle when you try to stop it.

Comment: What version of JBoss Fuse do you use. And what do you use in that bundle that uses network port 9001 and 9002?

Comment: you'd have to send more details - logs for example. ports 9001 and 9002 are usually used by CXF endpoints, when not using built-in CXF servlet

Comment: Thanks everyone, my issue has been solved. There were some processes by some other than root user which were running in backgrond. Point to note here is that when i tried "netstat anp | grep 9001" it didnt give me any running processe but "lsof | grep <urlOfServiceExposed>" gave me result which included processes by root user and some other user. So i just went to "FuseInstallDir/data/cache" did a " rm -rf  * " which deleted cache. And then started karaf with ./start. This time i didnt find any issue on startup